# Can I change result chunk size for simple select query on PR

Tags: geode

I tried to run a simple query like "select key, name from /region order by name limit 1000" on a Partitioned Region over a client/server topology. The performance was terrible. It took more than 10s for all 1000 records to be processed. My client application uses spring-data-gemfire. Debugging from client side showed that the results came back in 10 chunks. Each chunk could only have at most 100 records no matter how I change the socket buffer size and result object size (for example, I tested only returning key). Checking out the geode source code, I couldn't find where that 100 limit is set. I am thinking that if I can increase the number of object per chunk, I might be able to resolve this performance issue. But is that configurable?

Comment: Code below in AbstactOp was processed 10 times to process all chunks. That slowed down everything.        protected void processChunkedResponse(ChunkedMessage msg, String opName, AbstractOp.ChunkHandler callback) throws Exception {
             ...            do {
                msg.receiveChunk();
                callback.handle(msg);
            } while(!msg.isLastChunk());

        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that chunk size is controlled by the system property "BridgeServer.MAXIMUM_CHUNK_SIZE". So you could try setting that system property on the server to increase the chunk size.

I do wonder if your performance issue is actually due to the chunk size. The using order by on a partitioned region is going to be expensive, because it has to take data from all of the partitions and merge it before applying the limit. It also might be worth trying the same query without order by.